# Расстановка знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Имеется такое предложение из переписки в аське: "Если они захотят меня поздравить, буду рад, а нет () так нет".
После первого "нет" нужен ли какой-то знак препинания? И, если да, то какой: тире или запятая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Знаки не нужны.Повторяющиеся слова образуют единое целое.